# React with Formik and Material UI date of birth input component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

just starting out with React so go easy on me! I'm trying to build a component for inputting a date of birth, with a dropdown for each of 'Day', 'Month' and 'Year'. I've searched high and low online and be unable to find anything i've been able to implement. Here's my current approach which I know isn't the right way to go about it - if anyone has any suggestions for possible next steps or helpful reading I'd really appreciate it! (the rest of the implementation would follow a similar ideas as to what i have for months..

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function DobSelector() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={months}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.month}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Month" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const months = [
  { month: 'January' },
  { month: 'Febuary' },
  { month: 'March' },
  { month: 'April' },
  { month: 'May' },
  { month: 'June' },
  { month: 'July' },
  { month: 'August' },
  { month: 'September' },
  { month: 'October' },
  { month: 'November' },
  { month: 'Decemebr' },
];
```

Comment: This approach seems fine...how is formik involved?  You'll want to hook up the `value` and `onChange` or `onBlur` props of the Autocomplete to the formik values.  Can you post your code?

Comment: I haven't got as far as adding Formik - but my thinking was of adding to more arrays (one for days 1-31) and one for years (probably the last 100 or so). Seems like a lot of lines of code to do something like that - and then repeating the <Autocomplete /> component twice and pass in days and years respectively?

Comment: Do you really need to build this from scratch?  Have you checked out [material ui's ready-made date pickers?](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/).  Building accurate date pickers from scratch can get complicated, if you want to stay true to leap years and such